# User logged out of firebase server when different page loads

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm new to firebase, and I can't figure out how to keep the user logged in after going to a different page.  I'm able to successfully log in and post user data to the console on the log in page, but when I go to a different page and try to get the user information using *firebase.auth().currentUser*.  I initially had it immediately redirect to another page after the log in was completed, and turned it off to see if I was leaving the page before the information was relayed to the server, but that did not fix it.  I also tried to manually set the persistence to no avail.  I've looked around here and haven't found anything that fixes the problem.

Here is my sign in method (which is basically the same thing as what's on firebase docs), which is called when the sign in button on the form is clicked:

```
function signIn(){
    //getting credential input from form
    var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
    var password = document.getElementById('password').value;
    console.log(email, password)
    //calling firebase to sign in user
    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then(cred => {
        //confirmation that user signed in
        console.log("signed in");
    }).catch(function(error) {
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMsg = error.message;
        if(errorCode === 'auth/wrong-password') {
            alert('Wrong Password');
        }
        else {
            alert(errorMsg);
        }
        console.log(error);
    });
};
```

Comment: `.then(cred => {
        //confirmation that user signed in
        console.log("signed in");`   here the user input is made. Where do you want to direct your application the signed in User ?

Answer (score 0):

if I'm wrong, the others will correct me. As far as I know, when you log in with a user, even if you switch between pages, the information about that user is permanent . In other words, only the information that the user has added, updated and deleted will be displayed on your page. The user variable and other user information must be displayed in "signout".

```
// Think of it as a login page. assume that the user is redirected to a page after being logged in.
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then(() => {
            window.location.href = "index.html"; // let this be the page where user information should be displayed.
     })
```

So You also need a listener that handles login and logout status. This is where you can redirect users if they have successfully logged in.

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  if(user) {
    // this is where you can listen to user changes in index html and make your operations related to user here. 

firebase.auth().signOut() //  in this section you can do the logout function. Their information will be displayed until the user makes the logout. It continues until a new user logs in.
   .then(() => {
window.location.href = "login.html"
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`firebase.auth().currentUser` takes time to get data once a page is loaded. If you try to get it instantly, it will be `null`.

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
  }
});
```

This code will do whatever is in the function once Firebase has retrieved all the necessary data. @CanUver's answer did mention this code.
I show a loading page on my website until this is complete. This code snippet was from the Firebase Docs.

I'm not sure if this is your issue, but I remember having this problem.